# stolen article is the first result in google search

Tags: google-search

After moving my old domain as I have noted that [my post URL](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/) disappeared from the google search as shown below

[image]

Is it normal?

The main issue when I tried to search by the keyword [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/) I found out the first result is a stolen article with my identical image and content

[image]

[image]

## So I am Wondering

- How the stolen article get rank 1 in the search result
- Is it normal my migrated url not appear in google as sown in the image 1
- How to overcome this issue and get my post come back to the first result, should I reminded the old post url or reindex the new one

Please Help

**update**

301 redirect implemented correctly 4 months ago

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend filing the DMCA directly with Google Blogger instead of with Google Search, as it will take down the content at the source (blogspot.com) instead of just hiding it in results. Good luck!

Here is the link to file a DMCA specifically for Blogger:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/legal-removal-request?complaint_type=dmca&pid=4

As for the indexing, check your *new url* in Search Console and see what its index status is. It looks like Google has picked up the `blog` to `spgeeks` redirect properly, so it would be useful to inspect the final page url.

Answer (score 1):

To help recovering your ranks be sure you made a 301 from the old domain and url to the new one.

To prevent from the duplicate stolen article, you can ask for a google dmca action by using this link:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard
It's almost automatic and fast

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 301 redirect implemented correctly 4 months ago as shown in my updated answer, but I am wondering why in the first image the old article not indexed and the new one as well?